# I don't know what's wrong with my codes? It doesn't label out what I expect it to

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So basically, I have no idea what is the problem for this code. I am trying to complete a homework for a class. I did a coding on my tool which is generating a password accordingly to the checkboxes the user ticks and the entry the user writes. When I run this, there are no tracebacks with this, but when I select checkboxes and type in the entry box, and then I click generate, it doesn't label out the password. Also, I couldn't label out the entry box as well.
So, pls can you guys help me out with what is wrong with my codes?
P.S. My code is kind of long below but I hope you experts will understand.
You guys can copy and paste this onto IDLE and run it to see.

```
import random
import sys
import string
from tkinter import *
# Start Window
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("1200x500+130+200")

    def OnButtonClick(classGUIProgram):
        classGUIProgram.top = Toplevel()
        master = Tk()
        b = classGUIProgram.HappyButton(master)
        master.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(None)

window.title("Python Password Generator")
#window end

#title
w = Label(text="Secure Password Generator") 
w.pack()

w.config(font=("Courier", 70))
#title end

#value
rnum = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
rsl = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:26])
rbl = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:26])
rs = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*']
#value end

#label the password
def gpass():
    mtext = v.get()
    password = Label(text=mtext).pack()
    return
#label password end

#Checkbuttons
#checkbutton1
var1 = IntVar()
w1 = Checkbutton(text="Use Small Letters     e.g. abcde", 
variable=var1)
w1.pack()

#checkbutton2
var2 = IntVar()
w2 = Checkbutton(text="Use Big Letters        e.g. ABCDE", 
variable=var2)
w2.pack()

#checkbutton3
var3 = IntVar()
w3 = Checkbutton(text="Use Symbols            e.g. !@#$%", 
variable=var3)
w3.pack()

#checkbutton4
var4 = IntVar()
w4 = Checkbutton(text="Use Numbers          e.g. 12345", 
variable=var4)
w4.pack()
#checkbuttons end

length = StringVar()
var = StringVar()
v = StringVar()

#title label
l = Label(text="Type the password length you want below:")
l.pack()

t = Entry(textvariable=length).pack()
#title lable end

#button
button = Button(text = "Click To Generate Your Password", command = 
gpass, fg = 'Red').pack()
#button end

#generate random value according to the checkbuttons
def getin():
    a = []
    if w1.config(state=NORMAL):
         a.append(rsl[random.randint(*26/1)])
    elif w2.config(state=NORMAL):
        a.append(rbl[random.randint(*26/1)])
    elif w3.config(state=NORMAL):
        a.append(rs[random.randint(*8/1)])
    elif w4.config(state=NORMAL):
        a.append(rnum[random.randint(*9/1)])
    v = random.choices(getin(var(a)), k=str(length))
#generate value end


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I should point out that do not use tkinter, so if I make any gaffes, excuse me.
I have no idea what you are attempting to do with your use of `random`.
I suggest instead of whatever that is, use `random.sample(list, number_required)`.
I also suggest that you use `RadioButton` rather than `CheckButton`, as that will ensure that only one option is selected (I haven't done that below).
Your Generate button's callback has been set to `gpass` with no effort to call `getin` that actually generates the password.
Hopefully, the code below will point you in the right direction.

```
import random
import sys
import string
from tkinter import *
# Start Window
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("1200x500+130+200")

    def OnButtonClick(classGUIProgram):
        classGUIProgram.top = Toplevel()
        master = Tk()
        b = classGUIProgram.HappyButton(master)
        master.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(None)

window.title("Python Password Generator")
#window end

#title
w = Label(text="Secure Password Generator")
w.pack()

w.config(font=("Courier", 20))
#title end

#value
rnum = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
rsl = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:26])
rbl = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:26])
rs = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*']
passW = "None"
#value end

#generate random value according to the checkbuttons
def getin():
    try:
        l = int(length.get())
    except:
        l = 0
    if var1.get():
        passW = random.choices(rsl,k=l)
    elif var2.get():
        passW = random.choices(rbl,k=l)
    elif var3.get():
        passW = random.choices(rs,k=l)
    elif var4.get():
        passW = random.choices(rnum,k=l)
    password.configure(text=passW)
#generate value end

#Checkbuttons
#checkbutton1
var1 = IntVar()
w1 = Checkbutton(text="Use Small Letters     e.g. abcde",
variable=var1)
w1.pack()

#checkbutton2
var2 = IntVar()
w2 = Checkbutton(text="Use Big Letters        e.g. ABCDE",
variable=var2)
w2.pack()

#checkbutton3
var3 = IntVar()
w3 = Checkbutton(text="Use Symbols            e.g. !@#$%",
variable=var3)
w3.pack()

#checkbutton4
var4 = IntVar()
w4 = Checkbutton(text="Use Numbers          e.g. 12345",
variable=var4)
w4.pack()
#checkbuttons end

length = StringVar()
var = StringVar()
v = StringVar()

#title label
l = Label(text="Type the password length you want below:")
l.pack()

t = Entry(textvariable=length).pack()
#title lable end

#button
button = Button(text = "Click To Generate Your Password", command =
getin, fg = 'Red').pack()
#button end
password = Label(text=passW)
password.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Consider replacing the `CheckButtons` with `RadioButtons`

Edited to include the use of `random.choices` as identified by @user10987432, a much better "choice" than `sample` and to update the password label in-situ.

Comment: Why should they use RadioButtons? That implies that the four options are mutually exclusive. The CheckButtons allow the user to select the set of characters from which to generate the password.

Comment: But when I use this, it does print out the random passwords the computer generates, but if I click generate for a variety of times, the new passwords appear below the previous ones, and it is kind of hard to figure it out.

Comment: @user10987432 That is because in the OP's code they are mutually exclusive! I chose to use the OP's code, as this is a `homework` exercise, not rewrite it from scratch. If they present code way beyond their experience, it will be clear as day that they didn't write it. The idea is to help not replace.

Comment: @MarkLi I have edited my answer to address your issue and make use of `random.choices` for the reason explained and detailed by @user10987432

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this simple base:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Python Password Generator")
        self.geometry("320x240")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

A tkinter window which cannot be resized. Nice. Also, having a main function helps to understand program flow.

Then, add the rest. Notice, I moved the IntVars and StringVars into the body of the **init**, as well as the tkinter GUI elements themselves. I also made sure each element's parent was either a Frame (to keep the elements organized) or the Application instance itself. As far as generating the password goes, I would not use random.randint or random.sample (because random.sample has to grab unique items until there are none left, which means you will not be able to generate passwords of arbitrary length).

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Python Password Generator")
        self.geometry("320x240")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.var_lower = tk.IntVar()
        self.var_upper = tk.IntVar()
        self.var_symbols = tk.IntVar()
        self.var_digits = tk.IntVar()
        self.var_password_length = tk.StringVar()

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack()

        check_lower = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame,
            text="Use lowercase letters (a-z)",
            variable=self.var_lower)
        check_lower.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        check_upper = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame,
            text="Use uppercase letters (A-Z)",
            variable=self.var_upper)
        check_upper.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        check_symbols = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame,
            text="Use symbols (e.g. !@#$%)",
            variable=self.var_symbols)
        check_symbols.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        check_digits = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame,
            text="Use digits (0-9)",
            variable=self.var_digits)
        check_digits.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        entry_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        entry_frame.pack()

        label = tk.Label(
            entry_frame,
            text="Password length:")
        label.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        entry = tk.Entry(
            entry_frame,
            textvariable=self.var_password_length,
            width=16)
        entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

        button = tk.Button(
            entry_frame,
            text="Generate password",
            command=self.generate_password)
        button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W, pady=(10, 10))

        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(
            self,
            width=32)
        self.password_entry.configure(state="readonly")
        self.password_entry.pack()

    def generate_password(self):
        from random import choices
        from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

        try:
            password_length = int(self.var_password_length.get())
        except ValueError:
            return

        variables = [
            self.var_lower,
            self.var_upper,
            self.var_symbols,
            self.var_digits]

        character_sets = [
            ascii_lowercase,
            ascii_uppercase,
            "!@#$%^&*",
            digits]

        character_selection = "".join([charset for var, charset in zip(variables, character_sets) if var.get()])

        if not character_selection:
            return

        password = "".join(choices(character_selection, k=password_length))
        self.password_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.password_entry.insert(0, password)
        self.password_entry.configure(state="readonly")

def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

Comment: but, I want a big title like the one I had before in it, and the background yellow, can you pls do that for me as well, because I tried to put titles and background colors in, but tracebacks always happen.